# How can I find nth index value of a list using recursion in F#?

Tags: function, recursion, f#

A function called nth that takes an integer, n, and a list as arguments. The nth element of the list, indexed from 0, should be returned. n ≥ 0 and the list has at least n+1 elements.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: ive voted u up, because stack overflow can be a slightly passive aggressive place...maybe you should have a go, even if its just returning the 1st element, but takes the correct params

Comment: We need to see your effort in solving this. This site is about helping one solve problems that one has _attempted_ but currently failed to resolve. We do not solve your test questions for you.  (and a hint is that the function needs to return an Option - to handle edge cases).

Answer (score 1):

lets start with something like this...
here's your function, notice that it says 'rec' which means its recursive so the name of the function is in scope inside the function.
you match on the parameters, if the index is 0, you want the head of the list, which you can match using the '::' syntax

```
let rec nth (index: int) (list: list<'a>) = 
    match index, list with
    | 0, (head :: _tail) -> head
    | n, (_head :: tail) -> ?
```

you need to think what goes in the 2nd match.
and also note the compiler will give u a warning
"Incomplete pattern matches on this expression"

because what if you ask for the 1st element of a list of 0 items....so once you get this working u may want to think about how to handle that scenario